# Point to a DLL using a dynamic path

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

My problem is not exporting a function, but importing it. I know for sure that both the function and DLL both work because I have used a hard-coded path to point to the DLL.

This is what is currently working:

```
function RoamingAppDataPath: String; external 'C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\ss\Application\ss.dll';
```

However I need to point to the DLL with a dynamic value so what I tried to do is

1. Declare a global variable (DLLPath: String)
2. Assign DLLPath the value - RoamingAppDataPath+'\ss\Application\ss.dll'

Note: RoamingAppDataPath is a function that outputs the path to the roaming app data folder.

The code I am trying to run is:

```
function RoamingAppDataPath: String; external DLLPath;
```

When I compile the code, Delphi is telling me that it is expecting a constant expression:

```
E2026 Constant expression expected
```

What is the work around for this?

Comment: Show us the real definition of your `DLLPath` constant. The reason why I'm asking for this is clear from the [`E2026 error description`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/E2026_Constant_expression_expected_(Delphi)).

Comment: What' s about dynamic loading?
btw :Using string as parameter without sharemem won't be a good idea.

Comment: @TLama - I actually have DLLPath declared as a string variable

Comment: I've read your question wrong. I thought about `DLLPath` as a constant but you're trying to use variable... Sorry for misleading!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx#search_order_for_desktop_applications

Comment: Use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress. Also, string is not valid for interop. And why are you implementing a function that exists already in system libraries?

Comment: @David I was JUST about to say exactly those points :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to bind at runtime and that means you need to use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress:

```
var
  lib: HMODULE;
  RoamingAppDataPath: function: string;

lib := LoadLibrary(dllfilename);
if lib=0 then 
  RaiseLastOSError;
Pointer(RoamingAppDataPath) := GetProcAddress(lib, 'RoamingAppDataPath');
```

And then you can call it:

```
radp := RoamingAppDataPath;
```

Some comments:

- I don't know why you write this function when it exists in standard system libraries.
- Using string across DLL boundaries is liable to fail. You need to be using ShareMem and make sure that all code is built with the same Delphi version. Better to allocate the buffer in the calling code.

Comment: better to use SafeLoadLibrary or LoadLibraryEx

Comment: This is the appropriate answer, assuming the DLL might be anywhere.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I am not aware of the function you are referring to. Can you point me to it please?

Comment: It is SHGetSpecialFolderPath. How are you currently implementing the functionality in your DLL and why do you need a DLL at all?

Comment: It doesn't look like I need a DLL at all any more because my intent was to have the RoamingAppDataPath function in a DLL to be called by my other programs. What are the valid reasons to be using a DLL?

Comment: @peter that's a very subjective question which would be discouraged from asking on a site such as StackOverflow.

Comment: Pointless to create a DLL to wrap simple functionality provided by the system

Answer (score 2):

Even if you would be able to use a Variable, you would nowhere be able to set a value to DLLPATH, since already initalization would not be used if a static DLL can not be used.
You will have to use dynamic loadingif you want to define the path for the DLL.

```
  procedure Test;external 'Notexists.DLL';
var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  test;
end;

initialization
Showmessage('Hallo'); // will never be seen if test is used.
```

Comment: You can use [`delayed`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Libraries_and_Packages#Delayed_Loading) directive to load a library just when the function is called. Though as you say this case is a task for [`dynamic loading`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Libraries_and_Packages#Dynamic_Loading_.28Windows-only.29). [+1]